# SqlDependency finding row for changed column

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

```
void LoadData()
        {
            DataTable dtshow = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            //query get data show in grid

            SqlCommand cmdshow = new SqlCommand("SELECT a,b,c FROM XXX", con);

            //query check database change
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a,b,c FROM XXX", con);

            cmd.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency de = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            de.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(de_OnChange);

            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            dtshow.Load(cmdshow.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtshow;

        }
```

Hi, all my code is above,

When I update "a" column from the specific row, I need to find "b" and "c" from that row.

How can I get that ??

Thanks

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

Comment: I don't think you are able to do that within the OnChange event, SqlDependency only notifies you that 'something changed', not what changed

Comment: @D le what's the use of it then?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what SQL you are using but lets take PSQL:

its possible to add a [RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html) value when updating

for Example:

```
  UPDATE xxx SET a = <what ever>
  WHERE <your condition>
  RETURNING b,c;
```

Comment: take a loot at this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements